# How to customize Job timers SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, development, timer-jobs

I have created a job timer using visual studio, it is going to execute every month. And in a list it creates 1 new item per job timer execute. But the problem stays that if I change the date-time i.e if I set it to `01/01/2010` or to `01/01/2018` my job timer runs for every month which means that in my first example it runs approximately 60 times and it create 60 new items. Same thing happens with second example too. Is there any way to avoid this case?
I am changing the server date

Comment: Could you post the definition of the job? Which date are you changing?

Comment: I am Changing the server date